# Nodejs Promise.all without accumulating results

Tags: node.js, promise

Is it possible to wait for a collection of promises to resolve, like `Promise.all`, but without the values resulting from the promises being accumulated in memory?

Imagine I have:

```
let filesToDelete = [
  '/path/to/file.txt',
  '/another/path/to/file.txt',
  '/another/file.txt'
];
await Promise.all(filesToDelete.map(deleteFile));
```

Naturally, `deleteFile` returns undefined (asynchronously). When this code runs a useless Array containing `undefined` x 3 is accumulated in memory. As `filesToDelete` increases in size, an increasing amount of memory is needlessly consumed.

Comment: There isn't any way to do that. You shouldn't really be concerned about it. It's micro-optimization.

Comment: I agree that it's micro-optimization, but I'm surprised node doesn't have this capacity! Micro-optimization is to be avoided in 95% of situations, but in that last 5% it's pretty important to have the ability to micro-optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. The array will not be assigned to anything and hence not referenced by anything. This should lead to it being garbage collected soon.

Read more about JS memory management here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: This is mostly true, but I would imagine the array needs to stick in memory so long as `Promise.all(...)` remains unresolved. A particularly unfavourable scenario occurs when the array provided to `Promise.all` is huge, and any single promise in that array takes a long time to resolve.